# Generate random number in range [M....N] with mean X

Tags: php, random, numbers, probability, distribution

Generating a random number in the range [M..N] is easy enough. I however would like to generate a series of random numbers in that range with mean X (M < X < N).

For example, assume the following:
    M = 10000
    N = 1000000
    X = 20000
I would like to generate (a large amount of) random numbers such that the entire range [M..N] is covered, but in this case numbers closer to N should become exceedingly more rare. Numbers closer to M should be more common to ensure that the mean converges to X.

The intended target language is PHP, but this is not a language question per se.

Comment: Do you have an idea of what the distribution should look like? You can easily achieve this by using two uniform distributions (aka standard random function), one for [M..X] and one for [X..N] weighted so that the mean is X.

Comment: Interesting. So a uniform distribution in [M..X] would have a mean of (M+X)/2 and a uniform distribution in [X..N] would have a mean of (X+N)/2 right? And then weight those two means such that their EV is X...  is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, you'd simply start by flipping a weighted coin to decide which distribution to use. This satisfies your requirements but may not give the "shape" that you want.

Comment: If I wanted to, how could I affect the shape? Regardless, your suggestion is something I can already work with!

Comment: You would review your stats and look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_a_bounded_interval) for distributions with finite intervals.

Comment: I can't accept your 'comment' as an answer can I?

Comment: I'll summarize my comments as answer.

Comment: Or not, because I don't care enough about rep. Leaving it unanswered for a while may also give you more interesting responses.

Comment: Haha ok ... appreciate your time!

Comment: I was looking at various distributions... For the range X..N, I would like the distribution such that values near X are more likely than values near N (so higher values becomes increasly more rare). What would be suitable for that?

Comment: I tried to fit your needs in my answer. Seeing as it was unmarked as answer I assume it didn't do well enough, but it received no comment from you either. Is the distribution too linear for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this, and it would differ very much depending on your demands on precision. The following code uses the [68-95-99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule), based on the normal distribution, with a standard deviation of 15% of the mean.

It does not:

- ensure exact precision. If you need this you have to calculate the real mean and compensate for the missing amount.
- created a true normal distributed curve dynamically, as all the three chunks (68-95-99.7) are considered equal within their groups.

It does however give you a start:

```
<?php

$mean = (int)$_GET['mean']; // The mean you want
$amnt = (int)$_GET['amnt']; // The amount of integers to generate
$sd = $mean * 0.15;
$numbers = array();
for($i=1;$i<$amnt;$i++)
{
    $n = mt_rand(($mean-$sd), ($mean+$sd));
    $r = mt_rand(10,1000)/10; // For decimal counting
    if($r>68)
    {
        if(2==mt_rand(1,2)) // Coin flip, should it add or subtract?
        {
            $n = $n+$sd;
        }
        else
        {
            $n = $n-$sd;
        }
    }
    if($r>95)
    {
        if(2==mt_rand(1,2))
        {
            $n = $n+$sd;
        }
        else
        {
            $n = $n-$sd;
        }
    }
    if($r>99.7)
    {
        if(2==mt_rand(1,2))
        {
            $n = $n+$sd;
        }
        else
        {
            $n = $n-$sd;
        }   
    }
    $numbers[] = $n;
}

arsort($numbers);
print_r($numbers);

// Echo real mean to see how far off you get. Typically within 1%

/*
$sum = 0;

foreach($numbers as $val)
{
    $sum = $sum + $val;
}

 echo $rmean = $sum/$amnt; 
*/

?>
```

Hope it helps!